# How to execute a method with different arguments in parallel using multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method lets say "readFile(String filename)", I want to pass different file names and run this method in different threads and also write output in different files. This process should be parallel.

I am not good with multithreading concepts and not able to understand how to proceed.

Please help me on this

Comment: If your goal is to speed up I/O this will most likely not work anyhow because the transfer rate from your disk is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, implements `Runnable` with your file names

```
public class RunWithParameters implements Runnable {

    private String sourceFile;
    private String targetFile;

    public RunWithParameters(String sourceFile, String targetFile) {
        this.sourceFile = sourceFile;
        this.targetFile = targetFile;
    }

    public void run() {
        // your business logic with sourceFile and targetFile
    }
}
```

Then, run `RunWithParameters` with `ExecutorService` ,

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    executorService.submit(new RunWithParameters("sourceFile" + i, "targetFile" + i));
}
```

More information 
http://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial